# href="#top" Works By Itself

Tags: html

I added `<a href="#top">text</a>` to the bottom of a web page, then clicked on it without adding `id="top"` anywhere, and it worked (it brought me to top of page).

How come? Magic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is built into HTML5 according to the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#scroll-to-fragid):

> If target is the top of the document, then scroll to the beginning of
>   the document for the Document

In other words, it's a special case and you don't need to specify an ID for the top of the page.

See also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href):

> Note: You can use the special fragment "top" to create a link back to
>   the top of the page; for example `<a href="#top">Return to top</a>`

Comment: Any list of included IDs?